# Errors while trying to build an application with Cimg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, zlib, libpng, cimg

I am trying to use [CImg](http://cimg.eu/). I want to load pngs but to do so you need to add the dependency [Libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.htm) which also requires [zlib](https://zlib.net/).

I added all the required .h files directly from the zip file from their sites into my project using the add existing item on the file browser, but when I try to build my application I get the following [errors](https://pastebin.com/D81K8Jem).

What am I doing wrong?

Code to use CImg:

```
#define cimg_use_png
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to actually link against those libraries.

Comment: what would i have to put where to link it properly

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsgSnSG0O0U